# Performance considerations of a long (~30 minute) interval with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout

I'm making a water reminder Chrome extension that triggers a user notification every a period of time that is usually long (can reach up to 30 minutes), And I guess setTimeout wouldn't be the best choice regarding performance, so I started thinking about promise since they're made to operate asynchronously on long-duration, but that didn't work as well, so do you have any ideas?

thanks beforehand.

Comment: Send a notification... from what to where?  You might actually require a Web Worker for this, depending on the specifics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Brad I'm just giving the context of what I'm trying to do, What I'm trying to do can apply for any task, I'm looking for a code that will do a task after a long period of time(in this case 30 min) while still being performance efficient.

Comment: To do something after 30 minutes, `setTimeout()` is fine.  There is no performance issue there, nor does doing something async have any bearing whatsoever on the performance of your application.  That's why your question is unclear.  What's also unclear is what this notification is and where it's going.  It matters, because a Web Worker can handle this all in the background, even if the page is closed, assuming you're just hitting a server or something.  Also, browsers may actually suspend your JavaScript context if they think it's totally idle.  The details matter, and you should share them.

Comment: @Brad I edited the details you asked for, so would you add your answer as an answer for this question, And thank you.

Comment: What is a "water reminder"?  Again, what is sending a notification, and to where?  It's totally ambiguous whether you're sending data to some server, or just prompting the user with something.

Comment: I'm sending a chrome notification to the user, it's in the chrome extensions API, https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/richNotifications

Comment: Ok, so why did `setTimeout()` not work for you?

Comment: because I thought it's not the best performance efficient way and it might cause issues for weak devices, I was wrong.

Comment: For a chrome extension specifically, you might be better off using the dedicated API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I guess setTimeout wouldn't be the best choice regarding performance

`setTimeout()` is performant enough.  There is no issue there regarding performance.

> so I started thinking about promise since they're made to operate asynchronously on long-duration

No, that's not the purpose of a Promise.  Promises are just flow control tools.  They can help you do multiple things at once while you (a)wait for a result, but they aren't magically more performant than anything else.  They don't spin up any threads or anything like that either.

What I would do in this case is actually start an interval, every second, which compares the current time to any scheduled event that's supposed to occur at some particular time.  The benefit here is that the browser can be restarted and you can resume where you left off without having to worry about the system-managed context of `setTimeout()`.